# Javascript - how can I get a specific value from the route using regex?

Tags: javascript, regex

I would like to get the number shown in the route using regex. The number will always be shown in the fourth position although numbers can be at the third position and greater as well (third, fourth, fifth, etc...).

***(the "x" sign in the examples below can represent characters, numbers or symbols)***

example routes:

```
/first/second/third/3
/first/second-xxx/third-xxx-xxx/3
/first/second/third/3/
/first/second/third/3/xxx
/first/second/third/3/xxxx/x
```

Comment: We're gonna need some more information in order to answer this question.  What regex flavor are you using?  Is this the only number character in the string?  Can there be two slashes in a row?  You need to edit that information in so we can give you a better solution.  If you do happen to be using PCRE, and the other parts of the route can contain numbers, and there are no double slashes, this would be my solution: `^(?:.+?/){3}\K\d`.

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong I hope it makes more sense right now although I wasn't sure what do you mean by "two slashes in a row" and the "regex flavor".

Comment: A regex flavor is the way a particular regex engine parses the regex, since they are all slightly different.  I see you've specified that this is Javascript, so that is exactly what I was looking for.  As for double slashes, what should the regex do with a route like `/first//third/1/2`?  As far as counting slashes, the regex should return `1`, but is that what you want it to do?  Or should it return `2` and count the double slash as one slash?  Assuming the latter, I would update my solution like so: `^(?:.+?\/){3}(\d)`

Comment: @CharlieArmstrong Thank you for the explanation, and in regards to the double slashes It should return "1"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if I understand your question:

```
\/.*?\/.*?\/.*?\/(\d+)\/*.*
```

Comment: I changed the "\w" to "\d+" so I'll get only the numbers (in case there are characters as well) and more than one if they exist.

Comment: I changed too .

Comment: you forgot to add the "+" after the "d"

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

This answer does not solve the question since it was clarified that x can contain digits.

**Original answer**

If the number is the only number in the string, this should be enough:

```
[0-9]+
```

Matches any number with length 1 or greater.

Answer (score 0):

First, build the pattern to be searched before the number

- **^:** From the start of string
- **(\/\w+){3}:** Find three consecutive occurrences of '\SomeWordCharacters'
- **\/:** Followed by another '/'

Then, combine this with the number itself as a pattern to be output

- **(?<=^(\/\w+){3}\/):** Take the patten created above, and search for its occurence before the pattern you want to output.
- **\d+:** The pattern of interest that you actually want to output

All together:

```
(?<=^(\/\w+){3}\/)\d+
```